# Redirect IP address to PHP webpage

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm using XAMPP. I configured my Apache server using the IP address given by the wireless router in order for other users to access my webpage locally.

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 192.168.5.100:80
```

192.168.5.100 is my IP address.

Whenever the users type the address 192.168.5.100, they are directed to the phpMyAdmin page. I don't want them to see that page. I want to redirect them to my webpage which is "192.168.5.100/lbqms". How can I do this?

Comment: please rephrase your question title, some people might misunderstood what you want.

Comment: Look for `VirtualHost` documentation. In short, you need to declare a `VirtualHost` and set the `DocumentRoot` to the right path

Answer (score 4):

They are redirected to phpmyadmin page because of the index page in htdocs folder.
You will have to move the index page of your "lbqms" folder in htdocs.